# why BackHandler.addEventListener triggers several times when click on back button of device?

Tags: react-native, expo

I created expo push notification.
1) When I receive a notification I navigate to the screen of detailProduct using navigation.push and the same thing when I receive other notification.

2) I made this statement

```
BackHandler.addEventListener ('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress)
```

to listen to the event when I click on the back button.

```
handleBackPress = () => {
    console.log ("I clicked on the back button")
}.
```

My question is, when I navigate to the product detail screen for example 2 times, and I click on the back button, it's perfectly normal I go back to the previous screen. But the `handleBackPress()` function will be executed 2 times i.e. the message will be displayed 2 times:

```
I clicked on the back button
I clicked on the back button
```

Imagine when I navigate 5 or 6 times to the screen.
the situation will be complicated.

Why does `BackHandler.addEventListener` do that, and how do we run `BackHandler.addEventListener` once each time we click the back button?

Comment: are you using removeEventListener when you leave the detail screen?

Comment: @Auticcat. The problem is not solved

Comment: Try also to add return true inside the handleBackPress function after you have done the log

Comment: Share the code you use.

Comment: @Auticcat. I tried but could not go back to the previous screen

Comment: add a navigation.pop(1) before the return statement, so you manually make the screen disappear

Answer (score 1):

**Backhandler** function configuration shows no `boolean return value`.

The return value should be `true` to end the function normally.

**Usage**

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.push("you want Screen");
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null); // If your SCreen in Same Stack
     return true;
  }
```

Comment: I did it.
Yes, the function will be run once but you can not go back (you can not navigate to the previous screen) you're still in the same screen, and it's caused by the statement :return true;

Comment: @zakitutu Go to the screen you want to return to the function. You can use 'goback' if you are in the same stack. my answer updated